# Extended Screenshot On Android 12+ emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-12

It's easy to create an extended screenshot in physical android device running Android 12+, just like this: https://partnerdash.google.com/apps/simulator/#take-a-screenshot?l=en&model=Pixel_6_Pro

But how do we do so in an emulator? I don't see any `Capture more` button on emulator. Is it even possible in emulator?